# Connect to two databases using Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I was tried to connect two databases in application because I want to refer tables of both databases.Is it possible to connect two or more databases at the same application.I am using Hibernate libraries to connect to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with JSF because JSF is a view technology. In JDBC you connect to to different databases using getConnection method of DriverManager.In Hibernate you will need to configure one SessionFactory per database in your hibernate.properties or hibernate.cfg.xml. [As documentation says](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#tutorial-firstapp-configuration),

> You configure Hibernate's SessionFactory. SessionFactory is a global
>   factory responsible for a particular database. If you have several
>   databases, for easier startup you should use several 
>   configurations in several configuration files.